# How to open svn dump file from command line

Tags: svn, dump

I've created an svn dump for our project using svnrdump

```
svnrdump dump https://my.repo.com/project_name > my_dump.dump
```

Now I want to open it locally. How should I do it?

I've tried `svnadmin load ~/test/ < my_dump.dump` it gave me *test/format': No such file or directory* error, so I went with create first

```
svnadmin create ~/test
svnadmin load ~/test/ < my_dump.dump
```

It went without any errors, but it looks like it transferred all info into some kind of db, because the structure of the folder is not like my project. It looks smthng like this

`conf/
db/
format
hooks/
locks/
README.txt`

So, what should I do to extract the dump into some local folder and make its structure look how it was on the repo?

Answer (score 7):

Finally managed with it using *svn export* command (found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642917/how-to-extract-an-svn-dump) but it's for windows). To summarize, to extract svn dump file you need

```
svnadmin create /some/tmp/dir
svnadmin load /some/tmp/dir < my_dump.dump
svn export file:///some/tmp/dir /path/to/extracted/dir
```

Answer (score 0):

The `~/test` directory contains only the subversion repository, not working copy (what you want) so please run `svn checkout file:///YourHomedir/test /path/to/working/copy`.