# How to create offline SVN Repository backup on Windows?

Tags: git, svn

I have SVN repo and I would like to make a local copy which would server as backup when server would go down and I need all the information from repo like commit comments.

It needs to be transferable to a new computer if needed.

I have found this [solution](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001693831-Backing-up-your-SVN-repository) to do the dump, but can I open it on Windows without SVN Server?

Answer (score 0):

You would still need a server, but it can be a local one, like [VISUALSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/).

Then, with [svnadmin, you can extract your sump](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22252718/6309), and with [TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/), you can explore its content. All from your machine, without depending on a *remote* server.

Comment: That's what I am trying to avoid basically. Just to have some zipped file where I can go for commit comments history without going through all this trouble of local server etc. So such option is not possible?

Comment: @Jakub Check if TortoieSVN can explore your extracted repository directly, but I doubt it. The idea of a *local* server is for you to not depend on anything remote.